# How to display specific categories name in wp_tag_cloud

Tags: wordpress, taxonomy, tag-cloud

As normal `wp_tag_cloud` is show **Tag Cloud** by taxonomies, but it seems like not support to filter exclude for categories. except tag.

Have any ways to display that ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this with plugin this may help you

1. http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/sensitive-tag-cloud/
2. [http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/sensitive-tag-cloud/](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/widget-category-cloud/)
3. http://thedeadone.net/download/tdo-tag-fixes-wordpress-plugin/

Comment: Thank you, but it works for "tag cloud" that filter in specific categories, but i need show taxonomy as "categories name" as using code below `wp_tag_cloud(array('taxonomy'  => array('category')));`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this

```
$args = array('taxonomy' => 'category' );
 wp_tag_cloud( $args )
```

Comment: This tag is eject for all categories without "specific" categories as i need.